# Error with CognitiveJ/ExampleCode

Tags: java, api

I would like to use CognitiveJ ([GitHub from CognitiveJ](https://github.com/CognitiveJ/cognitivej/tree/rel.0.6.2)) but all I get is:

```
 Status:401; Body: {"error":{"code":"Unspecified","message":"Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure you are subscribed to an API you are trying to call and provide the right key."}}
```

Here is the Code:

```
public static String lic1 = "xxx";
public static String lic2 = "xxx";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new Bildkontrolle();

}

public Bildkontrolle() throws IOException {

    File imageFile = new File("E:\\DSC00306.jpg");

    new FaceRecognicion(lic1, lic2, imageFile);
}
```

And here the second class:

```
public FaceRecognicion(String lic1, String lic2, File imageFile) throws IOException {

    BufferedImage bufImage = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
    InputStream inpStream =  new FileInputStream(imageFile);

    FaceScenarios faceScenarios = new FaceScenarios(lic1,
            lic1);
    ImageOverlayBuilder imageOverlayBuilder = ImageOverlayBuilder.builder(bufImage);
    imageOverlayBuilder.outlineFacesOnImage(faceScenarios.findFaces(inpStream), RectangleType.FULL,
            CognitiveJColourPalette.STRAWBERRY).launchViewer();
}
```

Does anyone have an examplecode where I can look up how to use the API.
I stuck at the point where to send the Request.

Comment: What have you done already? Share some code.

Comment: From the site you give:  `FaceScenarios faceScenarios = new FaceScenarios(getProperty("azure.cognitive.subscriptionKey"), 
            getProperty("azure.cognitive.emotion.subscriptionKey"));`  other stuff are the same, you need to provide a valid subscription key when creating scenarios.